# Can cherries connect to anything?

Tags: piece-information, connections

Can the [Cherry Piece](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=22667#T=S&O=%7B%22st%22:%224%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22100%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D) connect to anything such as a hollow 1x1 round plate or a 1x1 round brick?

Comment: You've made it to the 6th most upvoted question for the Connections tag in 5 days! :)

Answer (score 18):

Yes, "Cherries / Cherry Pair" has 3.18mm connection also known as "bar". This type of connection is *in system* and is compatible with large variety of elements, including two you have mentioned.

Couple of examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]